# Running Hbase mapreduce job gives HBaseConfiguration NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: exception, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I have set the variable in `~/.bashrc`

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/lcoal/Hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.2.4.jar
```

but when i compile the code

```
java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/hadoopuser/Downloads/myjar.jar com.bigdata.uniquecoder.WordCountClass
```

It still gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
at com.bigdata.uniquecoder.WordCountClass.main(WordCountClass.java:57)

Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 1 more
```

**NOTE:** It works fine when i run it in eclipse but when running on top of hadoop gives this error.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a typo here `/usr/lcoal/...` or is it the same in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Its same as in ~/.bashrc

Comment: It should be `/usr/local/`...

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

The missing class will be present in `hbase-common-x.y.z.jar`

Update the `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH` with

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.4.jar
```

Or,

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Hbase/lib/
```

this will load all the jars under `$HBASE_HOME/lib`

Make sure `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH` contains necessary HADOOP libraries. Else, use the below `export` command in `~/.bashrc`

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/:$HADOOP_H‌​OME/share/hadoop/com‌​mon/lib/:$HADOOP_HOM‌​E/share/hadoop/hdfs/‌​:$HADOOP_HOME/share/‌​hadoop/hdfs/lib/:$HA‌​DOOP_HOME/share/hado‌​op/yarn/:$HADOOP_HOM‌​E/share/hadoop/yarn/‌​lib/:/usr/local/Hbase/lib/:$CLASSPATH
```

Comment: bin          conf  hbase-webapps  lib          logs        README.txt
CHANGES.txt  docs  LEGAL          LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt

That is what it returns.

Comment: ls /usr/local/Hbase/hbase-common* That hbase-common file is in lib folder.

Comment: hadoopuser@kali:~$ ls /usr/local/Hbase/lib/hbase-common*
/usr/local/Hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.4.jar
/usr/local/Hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.4-tests.jar